# WebSphere Liberty How to Set up Authenticated Users in server.xml?

Tags: authentication, websphere, websphere-liberty

How are authenticated users set up in WebSphere Liberty? I have followed the instructions listed here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7K4U_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.zseries.doc/ae/twlp_sec_rolebased.html and here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_sec_basic_registry.html

But I'm still missing some piece of the puzzle.

Here is what my ibm-application-bnd.xml looks like:

```
    <application-bnd>
        <security-role name="AllAuthenticated">
            <special-subject type="ALL_AUTHENTICATED_USERS" />
        </security-role>
    </application-bnd>
```

Here is the server.xml:

```
<basicRegistry id="basic" realm="WebRealm">
    <user name="wasadmin" password="wasadmin" />
    <user name="user1" password="test" />
    <user name="user2" password="test" />
    <group name="admin">
      <member name="wasadmin" />
   </group>

   <group name="users">
      <member name="wasadmin" />
      <member name="user1" />
      <member name="user2" />
   </group>
</basicRegistry>    

<administrator-role>
    <user>wasadmin</user>
</administrator-role>
```

Here is the error message

```
CWWKS9104A: Authorization failed for user wasadmin:defaultRealm while invoking MyApplication on /myapplication-mainPage. The user is not granted access to any of the required roles: [ROLE_AUTHENTICATED_USER].
```

Do I need to define a AllAuthenticated role? Is its name AllAuthenticated-role ? How do I get it to not look for the DefaultRealm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the page that helped me figure out the problem: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_sec_quickstart.html

This is what I added to the server.xml:

```
<enterpriseApplication location="MyApplication.ear">
<application-bnd> 
  <security-role name="ROLE_AUTHENTICATED_USER">
    <group name="admin" />
  </security-role>
</application-bnd>
</enterpriseApplication>
```

Comment: This configuration allows access to all the groups. How can we grant access to only admin group?